# Why don't pinned tabs in Chrome save when the browser is closed?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

In Google Chrome on both Windows and Ubuntu, pinned tabs are saved upon closing and reopened automatically the next time Chrome is started. With OS X, pinned tabs are not saved properly in Chrome and disappear with new browser sessions. Why is this behavior different and how can I get my pinned tabs to save?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert on OS X, but it seems that if you use the red 'x' to close the window, the application itself is not closed, only that window of the application. If you were to use Command + Q or quit via the application menu, the pins do save as expected.

Comment: Is there any way around this? Is there any hack allowing pinned tabs to reappear when the app is closed AND when the red X is clicked?

Comment: @LanceLafontaine - Check out RedQuits as suggested by this SU answer: http://superuser.com/a/371868/87406. I've never used it, so I can't comment on it, but if it works it should do the trick. http://www.carsten-mielke.com/redquits.html

Comment: works as expected in Safari though; red x and apple+w/q, then reopen and you're pinned tabs are still present.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine I found this solution, it kinda worked but not really, but worth giving it a shot as I might have mucked up some steps. https://www.joeldare.com/wiki/mac:fixing_google_chrome_pinned_tabs_on_macos

Comment: I can confirm RedQuits worked perfectly for me. Thanks!