# Can Chrome be set to pin tabs after closing the app AND closing the window?

Tags: google-chrome

I was inspired by this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112542/why-dont-pinned-tabs-in-chrome-save-when-the-browser-is-closed). It seems to be specific to OS X, but when I close a Chrome window with pinned tabs and don't explicitly quit the app, all my pinned tabs have disappeared. This is a real inconvenience, as resetting my 10+ pinned tabs everytime is not an option. **Is there any way (settings, extensions, etc) I can get Chrome to remember my pinned tabs when I close the *window***?

Comment: please clarify "don't explicitly quit the app"

Comment: If I go into the dock, right-click Chrome and quit, my pinned tabs reload. But if I just exit the window, they disappear.

Comment: so the cmd+shift+T does not work for you?